# Array.length seemingly not working; console.log shows otherwise

Tags: javascript

I want to eventually write contactList to the page but even though console.log is showing that contactList is properly receiving contacts being pushed from localStorage, its length remains at 1! And when I do try to iterate over contactList to write to the page, it doesn't work as expected and I see undefined where values should be.

```
var contactList = [];
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var data = window.localStorage.getItem("contacts");
    if(data){
        myData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("This is local storage:\n");
        console.log(myData);
        console.log("This is contact list before I push local storage:\n");
        console.log(contactList);
        contactList.push(myData);
        console.log("This is contact list after I push local storage:\n");   
        console.log(contactList);
        var j = contactList.length;
        console.log("This is the length of contact list:\n");
        console.log(contactList.length);
    
    }
}
```

Here's an example of my console window:

> This is local storage:
>
> form.js (line 12)
> [[[Object { firstname="hi",  lastname="hi",  number="hi"}], Object {
> firstname="hi",  lastname="hi",  number="hi"}], Object{ firstname="hi",  lastname="hi",  number="hi"}]
> form.js (line 13)
>
> This is contact list before I push local storage:
>
> form.js (line 14)
> []
> form.js (line 15)
>
> This is contact list after I push local storage:
>
> form.js (line 17)
> [[[[Object { firstname="hi",  lastname="hi",  number="hi"}], Object { firstname="hi",  lastname="hi",  number="hi"}], Object { firstname="hi",  > lastname="hi",  number="hi"}]]
> form.js (line 18)
>
> This is the length of contact list:
>
> form.js (line 20)
> 1

Comment: What does logging data and myData show?

Comment: You are pushing the entire array into the first index. Push does not add all the elements seperate

Comment: epascarello you are correct, thank you. I fixed it using concat.

Comment: Or you can just set it to contactList to start and there is no need to call that code onload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected outcome with [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). It looks like you want to use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

`push` will append whatever the argument is to a new element at the end of the array. If you add a string it will add the string. If you add an array it will add an array...as the last element. It will not flatten the resultant array. On the other hand `concat` will concat the two arrays and return a new array. The original array will be unchanged though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1]

console.log(a.length) // 0

var b = [2]

var c = a.push(b)

console.log(c) // [1, [2]] 

console.log(c.length) // 2
```

Try using concat():

```
var a = [1]

console.log(a.length) // 1

var b = [2]

var c = a.concat(b)

console.log(c) // [1, 2] <<< Desired behaviour

console.log(c.length) // 2
```